# Launch JavaFX project using reflection

Tags: java, javafx, reflection

I have a program, that downloads a Git repository, builds it and launches defined Main class. It works properly with ordinary projects, but when I want to launch a JavaFX project, I get strange errors like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.UI_Main
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:260)
    at app.UI_Main.main(UI_Main.java:31)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.UI_Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:248)
    ... 6 more
```

My Main class is:

```java
public class Main {
    private static final String GIT_ADDRESS = "https://github.com/lerryv/CheckCheckerDesktop";
    private static final String MAIN_PATH = "app/";
    private static final String MAIN_CLASS = "app.UI_Main";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GitAPIException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Git.cloneRepository().setURI(GIT_ADDRESS).setDirectory(Paths.get("./dir/").toFile()).call();
        Collection<String> result = compile(Paths.get("./dir/src/").toFile());
        String command = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/../bin/javac -d dirOut -cp \".:json-simple-1.1.jar\" " + result.join(" ");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                new URL[]{
                        new File("dirOut/").toURI().toURL()
                }
        );
        Class clazz = urlClassLoader.loadClass(MAIN_CLASS);
        Method main = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
        assert Modifier.isStatic(main.getModifiers());
        main.invoke(null, (Object) args);
    }
    private static Collection<String> compile(File directory) {
        assert directory.isDirectory();
        Collection<String> result = new Collection<>();
        boolean hasFiles = false;
        for (File file: directory.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                result.addAll(compile(file));
            } else {
                if (!hasFiles) {
                    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    String extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    if (extension.equals("java")) hasFiles = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hasFiles) result.add(directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/*.java");
        return result;
    };
}
```

At first I thought it cannot find the class, but when I removed the method.invoke statement, errors disappeared. Why does it happen and are there any workarounds?

Comment: Can you maybe explain why you are trying to download & compile & run project like that? Instead of just giving finished application?

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

This is starting another process, so after this line is executed compilation is not yet finished, you need to wait for this process to end, and probably you should also handle output/error stream of process to check if it succeed or not.

```
Process compileProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
compileProc.waitFor();
```

Also I don't know what are you trying to do, but remember that not everyone might have compiler available and configured `java.hame` property, or configured it to different java version. (like older one and your code will not compile or newer one and you code will not run)

Answer (score 0):

The program opens a new thread to start the project, but it executes the next line without monitoring its completion, so the thread can be removed if it is not necessary. If necessary, you need to write a monitoring thread to monitor and schedule all threads so that it can continue to execute after it has finished its work. Tasks of the main thread.